# UPDATE table JOIN table SET only updates unique id's

Tags: mysql

I want to update **Table B** with `sum(aa)` from **Table A** where `A.id=B.id` and into the column set by `A.d` (E.g. **A:**`223, d1, 5` updates **B:** id `223`, column `d1 = d1 + 5`).

```
TABLE A                 TABLE B
id      d      aa       id      d1      d4     d7
--- +-------+----       ----+-------+-------+-----
223 |   d1  |   5       221 |   0   |   5   |   0 <
224 |   d1  |   5       222 |   0   |   5   |   0 <
225 |   d1  |   5       223 |   5   |   0 < |   0 <
226 |   d1  |   5       224 |   5   |   0 < |   0 <
    |       |           225 |   5   |   0 < |   0 <
221 |   d4  |   5       226 |   5   |   0 < |   0 <
222 |   d4  |   5       < = missing                     
223 |   d4  |   5                               
224 |   d4  |   5                               
225 |   d4  |   5                               
226 |   d4  |   5                               
    |       |           EXPECTED:           
221 |   d7  |   5       id      d1      d4      d7
222 |   d7  |   4       ----+-------+-------+------
223 |   d7  |   5       221 |   0   |   5   |   5
224 |   d7  |   5       222 |   0   |   5   |   5
224 |   d7  |   5       223 |   5   |   5   |   5
225 |   d7  |   5       224 |   5   |   5   |   10
226 |   d7  |   5       225 |   5   |   5   |   5
226 |   d7  |   5       226 |   5   |   5   |   15
226 |   d7  |   5
```

**Query:** (As I can't use dynamic column names I need a `CASE WHEN THEN`)

```
UPDATE `TABLE_B` `B`
JOIN(
    SELECT `id`,`d`,SUM(`aa`)`aa` 
    FROM `TABLE_A` GROUP BY `id`,`d` 
    ) `A` 
ON `A`.`id`=`B`.`id`
SET 
`d1`= CASE `B`.`d` WHEN "d1" THEN `A`.`d1`+`B`.`aa` ELSE `A`.`d1` END,
`d2`= CASE `B`.`d` WHEN "d2" THEN `A`.`d2`+`B`.`aa` ELSE `A`.`d2` END,
`d3`= CASE `B`.`d` WHEN "d3" THEN `A`.`d3`+`B`.`aa` ELSE `A`.`d3` END,
`d4`= CASE `B`.`d` WHEN "d4" THEN `A`.`d4`+`B`.`aa` ELSE `A`.`d4` END,
`d5`= CASE `B`.`d` WHEN "d5" THEN `A`.`d5`+`B`.`aa` ELSE `A`.`d5` END,
`d6`= CASE `B`.`d` WHEN "d6" THEN `A`.`d6`+`B`.`aa` ELSE `A`.`d6` END,
`d7`= CASE `B`.`d` WHEN "d7" THEN `A`.`d7`+`B`.`aa` ELSE `A`.`d7` END
```

The problem is this only updates unique id's. It takes `223, 224, 225, 226` from `d1`, then only `221, 222` from `d4` and nothing from `d7`, instead of updating 16 values (4x d1, 6x d4, 6x d7).

So where in the `JOIN` am I doing wrong?

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7MP2mg68pzc8YZZZ63HM6q/3)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to update the B table, yet your query says the opposite.  Please tell us what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I'd find it easier to read without all the ``s

Comment: You're right, my wrong

Comment: Voting to close as unclear because the OP does not even know which table is being updated, or which columns belong to each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution by using two subqueries to first make a full table  with all columns in it and only one row per `id`:

```
SELECT 
`id`,
CASE `d` WHEN "d1" THEN SUM(`aa`) ELSE 0 END AS `a1`, 
CASE `d` WHEN "d4" THEN SUM(`aa`) ELSE 0 END AS `a4`,
CASE `d` WHEN "d7" THEN SUM(`aa`) ELSE 0 END AS `a7` 
FROM `TABLE_A`
GROUP BY `id`,`d`
```

Giving (example only for id's 221 and 226):

```
id   d1  d4  d7
----+---+---+----
221 | 0 | 5 | 0
221 | 0 | 0 | 5
226 | 5 | 0 | 0
226 | 0 | 5 | 0
226 | 0 | 0 | 15
```

Then make sure there is only one row for each `id`:

```
SELECT
    `id`,
    SUM(`a1`) `a1`,
    SUM(`a4`) `a4`,
    SUM(`a7`) `a7`
FROM(
 .... previous select ...
)
GROUP BY `id`
```

Giving (example only for id's 221 and 226):

```
id   d1  d4  d7
----+---+---+----
221 | 0 | 5 | 5
226 | 5 | 5 | 15
```

Now I could update Table B:

```
UPDATE `TABLE_B` `B`
JOIN(   
SELECT
    `id`,
    SUM(`a1`) `a1`,
    SUM(`a4`) `a4`,
    SUM(`a7`) `a7`
FROM(
    SELECT 
    `id`,
    CASE `d` WHEN "d1" THEN SUM(`aa`) ELSE 0 END AS `a1`, 
    CASE `d` WHEN "d4" THEN SUM(`aa`) ELSE 0 END AS `a4`,
    CASE `d` WHEN "d7" THEN SUM(`aa`) ELSE 0 END AS `a7` 
    FROM `TABLE_A`
    GROUP BY `id`,`d`
    ) `C`
GROUP BY `id`
)`A`
ON `A`.`id`=`B`.`id`
SET
    `d1`=`d1`+`a1`,
    `d4`=`d4`+`a4`,
    `d7`=`d7`+`a7`
```

Maybe there are better solutions, but this works.